# MSTest Unit test attributes check

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, attributes

For regulatory reason all unit tests in our solution have to have some attributes set. Is there a way to check in visual studio if some specific attributes (like CREATOR, REVIEWER, REVIEWDATE, ...) are set within the VSMDI-list of the solution?
Further I have to check if the "CREATOR" attribute is equal to the "REVIEWER" attribute.
The goal is to deliver a list (Text, Excel, whatever) to my Scrum team with all these "wrong set attributes", so that they can fix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running all the needed Tests within Visual Studio 2010 you get a TRX-file containing all the details of the executed tests. If you have put some attribute on these tests,you'll find them also in the TRX-file. Now you have to write an XML parser to read the attributes you need and work with this data. I extracted them into Excel and worked further with the data into the Excel map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to check for the attributes and then create your Excel/Text list. You can do this as a [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) task and plug it into pre/post build actions of your Unit test project. See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2006/01/21/515834.aspx) for an example on how to create a custom MSBuild task.